# Splitting a list in bash

Tags: bash, shellcheck

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

list="a b c d"

for item in ${list[@]}; do
  echo "${item}"
done
```

When I run it this is the output:

```
a
b
c
d
```

This is **exactly** what I want. However, `shellcheck` hates this and throws an error:

```
for item in ${list[@]}; do
            ^-- SC2068: Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.
```

But, when I double quote the variable the output of the script changes to this:

```
a b c d
```

Which is *not* what I want.

Is shellcheck right and should I modify the way I try to extract the items from the variable, but how? Or should I just tell `shellcheck` to ignore this?

Comment: Because `list` is *not* a real array.

Comment: Replace `${list[@]}` with `$list`.

Comment: @iBug : I've updated the question by removing the term 'array'

Comment: Also updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not an array:

```
list="a b c d"
```

You're just assigning `list` to a string of length 7.

To make it a real array:

```
list=(a b c d)
```

Then with `for item in "${list[@]}"`, you get the correct result.

---

For your updated question, you should just use `$list` instead of `${list[@]}`, because `list` isn't an array.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when using code below:

```sh
redhatCatalogs=("certified-operators" "redhat-marketplace")

for catalog in ${redhatCatalogs[@]}; do
  ...
```

Notice I am missing the quotes, after adding the quotes, problem was solved:

```sh
redhatCatalogs=("certified-operators" "redhat-marketplace")

for catalog in "${redhatCatalogs[@]}"; do
  ...
```

So in conclusion, consider the quotes as well!: `"${redhatCatalogs[@]}"`